# cannot connect to local postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am new to docker and postgres and this is really puzzling to me. After pulling the postgres 14.1 alpine image, I created a container from the image called postgres14.1 setting the user and password:

```
docker run --name postgres14.1 -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d postgres:14.1-alpine
```

Then I created a database called 'simple_bank' on the container:

```
docker exec -it postgres14.1 createdb --username=root --owner=root simple_bank
```

Before connecting to the database in TablePlus or VSCode with postgres extension, I tried to access in the terminal:

```
docker exec -it postgres14.1 psql simple_bank
```

And it works fine. In the terminal , `\du+` confirms `root` is indeed a superuser in the `simple_bank` database:

```
Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of | Description 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 root      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}        |
```

Then I tried to connect via TablePlus with the following config:

```
Host/Socket: 127.0.0.1
Port:5432
User:root
Password:secret
Database:root
```

This can't be connected saying role `root` doesn't exit. If leave the user blank and set database to `postgres` then it connects but it can't find the `simple_bank` database created from the command line.

Comment: Why do you tell it to connect to root if you want to connect to simple_bank?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, the problem is because I already have a local instance of postgres installed and it by default also connects to port 5432 on my local machine. Hence in creating the postgres container, I need to choose a different port on local host.
So changing the below docker command and then connect locally using port 5433 fixes the problem.

```
docker run --name postgres14.1 -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d postgres:14.1-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

use `host.docker.internal` insted of `localhost`
basically replace `DB_HOST with host.docker.internal`